# Use java annotations in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, annotations

```java
a.b(new C() {
  @Handler
  public void d() {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
});
```

I tried to translated it to clojure:

```java
(.b a (proxy [C] []
  (^{Handler {}}
    d [] (println "hello world"))))
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Is this correct? How should I add java annotation to a method?

Comment: Could you please be more verbose about "But unfortunately it doesn't work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally suggest writing your interop code in Java: present an API that fits what Java wants, and implement it with calls to your Clojure functions. The Clojure->Java translation layer is just not that rich for creating types that are not just `reify` or `defrecord`, and I find it a big burden to do anything fancy, like handle annotations, or extend classes.

Answer (score 1):

There's documentation for this [here](https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_java_annotation_support)

Based on that I'd try something along the lines of

```clj
(deftype ^{Handler true} CC [] ...)
(.b a (CC.))
```

There's no mention of proxy/reify support, that's why I'm creating a new class explicitly.

Comment: It seems `deftype` only supports interfaces, is there anyway to extends from class?

Comment: @swwind no there isn't. There are interesting libraries like [JiSE](https://github.com/athos/JiSE) on their way, but the simplest path in this case is to write it in java. If you told us your exact use case there might be a different way to solve it.